# toast warning when page loads jquery

Tags: jquery, alert, toast

How do I get a toast message when the page loads?

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#type-success").on("click",function() { 
        toastr.success("Have fun storming the castle!","Miracle Max Says");
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get it to fire when the page loads? Or on click? Your question conflicts with the code you've shared

Comment: I don't have very good English, I'm sorry. I use Google translate, sometimes it can translate incorrectly. I want toast alert when the page loads.

Comment: Remove the `.on("click"` line and just have `$(function() { toastr.success("loaded") });`